# Multivariate Linear Regression with exponential trend-line

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

The dataset that I'm working with has 2 independent variables (qty, volume) and 1 dependent variable (cost).  When I plot individual X with Y, it turns out **qty vs cost** gives an exponential decay trend line while **volume vs cost** gives a linear relationship.

I'm trying to come up with a linear model (since it's beginner-friendly) to predict the cost when a new input, volume set is given.  I tried to excel and while the statistic output looks reasonable, the predicted values are off quite a lot.  I read up on some articles and there is something regarding log transformation so that both qty and volume have a linear relationship with cost.  I'm not sure if log transformation applicable in this situation.  What would be the best way to approach this problem?

I plan to use R instead of excel next.

Here are some outputs of what I've done

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note**: Thickness, width, and height essentially become volume so it doesn't affect the data much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest transforming "qty" into the log space. Even, you can do this using Excel. You can make a new column (for example qty_log), which is equal to the log of "qty". Then, you can fit a linear regression as follows:

$cost = a1 * log(qty) + a_2 * volume + a_0$

You will get much better results in this case.

This equation simply means that try to fit a model using volume and log of qty for predicting cost. You did so before but you used qty instead of log(qty)

Comment: Thank you, can you explain in your equation what the term after a1 is?  It looks like qtylog, not sure what it means.

Comment: I add two more lines. Just try to transform qty to log space as I explained using excel. Then, fit a model as you did before. You just need to use the new column (which is log of qty) instead of using qty directly.

Comment: I tried it and the predicted values come out much closer to the expected.  There's one issue with taking the log(qty) however is that if qty is 1, then log(qty) becomes 0 and it throws off the prediction.  I read a discussion saying to do log(qty+1) instead however it gives higher SE.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on your data. In most cases, log(qty+1) is the best solution.